# Prove $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am given that $L/K$ is a finite extension of fields and that $[L : K] = 25$ and want to prove that $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ is abelian.

I also had to show that $|\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)|$ divides $[L : K]$.

I did this by letting $L^G$ be the fixed field of $G$ with $[L: L^G] = |G| = |\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)|$
then by Tower Law    $[L: K] = [L: L^G][L^G: K] = |G|[L^G : K]$.

Back to showing $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ is abelian, I've noted that as $[L: K]$ is $25$ which means $|\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)|$ is either $1, 5$ or $25$.

If it has order $25$, then it is abelian as all groups of order $p^2$ (with p being prime) are abelian.

If it has order $1$ then it is the trivial group and therefore abelian.

I still need to show it for when $|\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)| = 5$.

Am I heading in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: All groups of order $1,5,25$ are abelian.

Answer (score 1):

For Galois extensions $L/K$ the order of the Galois group is equal to the field degree. So we have $|{\rm Gal}(L/K)|=[L:K]=5^2$. Since all groups of order $p^2$ are abelian, as you have noted, we are done.

Reference: 
[Proof of Order of Galois Group equals Degree of Extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980455/proof-of-order-of-galois-group-equals-degree-of-extension)

Comment: I haven't been told that the extension L/K is normal and separable though so can't jump straight to the order of the Galois group equaling the field degree

Comment: This may be convention, but for me $Gal(L/K)$ is only defined if the extension is Galois; otherwise it is just $Aut(L/K)$. But anyway, as I said, groups of order $1$ or $5$ are trivially abelian.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! Wasn't sure about the $5$

Comment: Every group of order $p$ is abelian, for $p$ prime. Actually, there is only one such group, namely $C_p$, by Lagrange.

Comment: Dietrich, @Wad, for example Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I* denotes $Gal\, L/K$ what you denote $Aut(L/K)$. Irrespective of whether the extension $L/K$ is Galois or not. So that convention is not universal. Judging from what I've seen here quite a few people only denote the automorphism group $Gal(L/K)$ when it is known that the extension is Galois. May be some other textbooks define it that way? Can't check, and I'm a loyal disciple of Jacobson anyway :-) Here it won't use Jacobson's notation, though. Too high a risk of confusing someone.

Comment: Of course, your comment under the OP still settles the question.